# Create trie on ssd. How to manage object movements to other locations?

Tags: c#, .net, trie

I need to create a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) on ssd. I can't use much RAM as the trie is very big, but 4 GB RAM are no problem.

Currently I think about doing it the following way:

- Using one memory mapped file
- Having objects serialized with protobuf, changing pointers to other objects with file position and length

Now I am looking for tools that could help. I have problems when a object (node) gets larger. I need to find a new location in the file for this object, changing all links to this object. And then I am left with a gap in my file. Then I would need to compress my tree and change all positions of all objects to close some gaps. Leaving some space after each object would lead to very much space requirements.

Do you know libraries or have some hints to solve this problem or that could help programming all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to provide a new angle to this problem here: Why don't you store the trie-nodes in a database like SQLite? SQLite is fast, well tested and feature rich. It is likely to do a much better job than you.

Relational databases are not really made to store trees, but they can. I cannot think of any particular query problem that you could solve significantly better by writing a custom trie on-disk data structure.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: this is for the memory mapped file approach, I really liked your intuition on that.

**Edit2**: every time I say "point" or "pointer", I actually mean a zero-based offset from the beginning of the file. Since written data never moves around, the nodes' position acts as global identifiers for them.

A node shouldn't really get larger though. The way I'd do it is have the node be like:

- the character held by the node (UTF-8 encoded if needed)
- an array of say 8 items that hold pointers to its children. this is statically dimensioned with `NULL` (or 0) specifying no more children. This list never gets shorter, only larger.
- a pointer to a piece of memory that holds another array of children pointers, also statically dimensioned. you always have this even if you don't actually need the extra space, you can just write `NULL` in it.

  - if pointing to actual valid memory, right after the list you'd have another pointer to an extra list if needed, so you can go however far you need to. Alternatively, the second list can be big enough to hold all characters.

As an alternative, statically allocate memory enough for all characters from the start. This may get too large too fast though, depending on the sparseness of your tree.

Either way, note that with this way your actual node size *never increases*, it has a static length. You can add the extra nodes or extra list chunks at the end of your file as needed, and hold a root at the beginning to point to all its children so you never have to mess with the head.

Comment: But at any node there could be up to 65536 sub nodes (based on the next char). So your suggestion is to have a kind of child node type attached to every node with 8 items and they have 8 sub items and so on? So the child node type is like a binary tree? Doing so I would need to traverse (update) the whole binary tree on each update. How would you deal with nodes not only having one character, but more than one ("t" with the sub node "ree" - patricia trie)?

Comment: No no, the child list would be more like a linked list with each entry having 8 or whatever children at a time (an optimization really). So you'd have `['a' [ch1 ch2 ch3 ch4 ch5 ch6 ch7 ch8] -->2ndpart]`, and `2ndpart` (a memory offset) would hold `[[ch9 ch10 ch11 ch12 ch13 ch14 ch15 ch16] -->3rdpart]` and so on.

Comment: And I wouldn't deal with nodes like that at all. `tree` is `t`->`r`->`e`->`e`. It won't change the way the tree looks if you add a word like `treble` this way.

Comment: hmm, but when I don't have the word treble or other words following the "t", then I need to have many nodes. I am storing very much longer words, so I think this could lead to much fail invested seek operations. With the linked list layout I would need to have 80 seek requests to get to the 80thpart. It is a good idea to solve my problem, but leading to too much seek requests (although they are fast at ssds, but I have very much threads accessing this trie).

Comment: longer words are fine, it means the children lists are short. And you can make the static children list as long as you want (I think 32 or so elements are enough for most words). Will you really have hundreds of children for the 2nd letter? 3rd letter? Try building your actual tree and run some statistics on it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure You can't posit that the English language is more complex, word-wise, than a general-purpose file system. That's basically how Linux's inode structures work (most file system structures in fact, but I'm only familiar with Linux's).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will give you an upvote, but usr's answer is very cool. I can outsource the whole problematic to sqlite. So I will accept this answer.